# Oracle SQL compliant regular expression for below expression

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am trying to convert below regular expression to oracle compliant regular expression syntax. It seems that the look-around is not supported in Oracle. Any idea how should I make it work.

```
(\b((xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.){1,2}[a-z]{2})(?=\z|[/\s])|(\b((xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.){1}[a-z]{3,})(?=\z|[/\s])
```

Below query should identify the website domain accurately.

```sql
select 1
from   dual
where  REGEXP_LIKE(
         LOWER('sme other site https://www.mywebsite.com and few'), 
         '(\b((xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.){1,2}[a-z]{2})(?=\z|[/\s])|(\b((xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.){1}[a-z]{3,})(?=\z|[/\s])'
       )
```

Comment: Just change the lookaheads to `(?:\z|[/\s])` or `(\z|[/\s])`

Comment: both do not work. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/27192

Comment: Oracle does not support word-boundaries `\b` or look-ahead so you need to fix both. (Or, if you have Java enabled in the database, you can [create a Java method to parse the regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74351821/1509264) and call that from SQL.)