# Regular Expression: changing matching method from OR to AND

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a regular expression like the following: (Running on Oracle's `regexp_like()`, despite the question isn't Oracle-specific)

```
abc|bcd|def|xyz
```

This basically matches a `tags` field on database to see if `tags` field contains `abc` **OR** `bcd` **OR** `def` **OR** `xyz` when user has input for the search query "`abc bcd def xyz`".
The `tags` field on the database holds keywords separated by spaces, e.g. "cdefg abcd xyz"

On Oracle, this would be something like:

```
select ... from ... where 
   regexp_like(tags, 'abc|bcd|def|xyz');
```

It works fine as it is, but I want to add an extra option for users to search for results that match all keywords. How should I change the regular expression so that it matches `abc` **AND** `bcd` **AND** `def` **AND** `xyz` ?

Note: Because I won't know what exact keywords the user will enter, I can't pre-structure the query in the PL/SQL like this:

```
select ... from ... where 
   tags like '%abc%' AND
   tags like '%bcd%' AND
   tags like '%def%' AND
   tags like '%xyz%';
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this with Oracle regexp. In PCRE you can do it with lookaheads (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator/470602#470602) but Oracle doesn't support that.

Comment: I would like to suggest that in your OR example you tighten up the match criteria so that the string is preceded by a space or the start of the line, and proceded by a space or the end of the line, thus eliminating conditions where the string may be part of a larger word.  Especially if you are matching user input, who knows what they will enter, bless their hearts.  `REGEXP_LIKE(tags, '(^| )(abc|bcd|def|xyz)( |$)');`

Answer (score 1):

You can split the input pattern and check that all the parts of the pattern match:

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY(
         WITH input (match) AS (
           SELECT 'abc bcd def xyz' FROM DUAL
         )
         SELECT 1
         FROM   input
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(match, '\S+')
         HAVING COUNT(
                  REGEXP_SUBSTR(
                    t.tags,
                    REGEXP_SUBSTR(match, '\S+', 1, LEVEL)
                  )
                ) = REGEXP_COUNT(match, '\S+')
       )
```

---

Or, if you have Java enabled in the database then you can create a Java function to match regular expressions:

```sql
CREATE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED RegexParser AS
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexpMatch {
  public static int match(
    final String value,
    final String regex
  ){
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

    return pattern.matcher(value).matches() ? 1 : 0;
  }
}
/
```

Then wrap it in an SQL function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION regexp_java_match(value IN VARCHAR2, regex IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER
AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'RegexpMatch.match( java.lang.String, java.lang.String ) return int';
/
```

Then use it in SQL:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  regexp_java_match(tags, '(?=.*abc)(?=.*bcd)(?=.*def)(?=.*xyz)') = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the idea being counting that the number of matches is == to the number of patterns:

```
with data(val) AS (
    select 'cdefg abcd xyz' from dual union all
    select 'cba lmnop xyz' from dual
),
targets(s) as (
    select regexp_substr('abc bcd def xyz', '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL)  from dual
    connect by regexp_substr('abc bcd def xyz', '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL) is not null
)
select val from data d
join targets t on 
    regexp_like(val,s)
group by val having(count(*) = (select count(*) from targets))
;
```

Result:

```
cdefg abcd xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [dynamic SQL](https://blogs.oracle.com/connect/post/working-with-cursors) will be needed for this. The match all option will require individual matching with logic to ensure every individual match is found.

An easy way would be to  build a join condition for each keyword. Concatenate the join statements in a string. Use dynamic SQL to execute the string as a query.

The example below uses the customer table from the [sample schemas provided by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/comsc/installing-sample-schemas.html).

```
DECLARE

  -- match string should be just the values to match with spaces in between
  p_match_string           VARCHAR2(200) := 'abc bcd def xyz';
  -- need logic to determine match one (OR) versus match all (AND)
  p_match_type             VARCHAR2(3) := 'OR';
  l_sql_statement          VARCHAR2(4000);
  -- create type if bulk collect is needed
  TYPE t_email_address_tab IS TABLE OF customers.EMAIL_ADDRESS%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  l_email_address_tab      t_email_address_tab;

BEGIN

  WITH sql_clauses(row_idx,sql_text) AS
  (SELECT 0 row_idx -- build select plus beginning of where clause
         ,'SELECT email_address '
         || 'FROM customers '
         || 'WHERE 1 = '
         || DECODE(p_match_type, 'AND', '1', '0') sql_text
   FROM DUAL
   UNION
   SELECT LEVEL row_idx -- build joins for each keyword
         ,DECODE(p_match_type, 'AND', ' AND ', ' OR ') 
          || 'email_address'
          || ' LIKE ''%' 
          || REGEXP_SUBSTR( p_match_string,'[^ ]+',1,level) 
          || '%''' sql_text
   FROM   DUAL
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(p_match_string) - LENGTH(REPLACE( p_match_string, ' ' )) + 1
  )
  -- put it all together by row_idx
  SELECT LISTAGG(sql_text, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY row_idx)
  INTO l_sql_statement
  FROM sql_clauses;

  dbms_output.put_line(l_sql_statement);

  -- can use execute immediate (or ref cursor) for dynamic sql
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_statement
  BULK COLLECT
  INTO   l_email_address_tab;

END;
```

| Variable | Value |
| --- | --- |
| p_match_string | abc bcd def xyz |
| p_match_type | AND |
| l_sql_statement | SELECT email_address FROM customers WHERE 1 = 1 AND email_address LIKE '%abc%' AND email_address LIKE '%bcd%' AND email_address LIKE '%def%' AND email_address LIKE '%xyz%' |

| Variable | Value |
| --- | --- |
| p_match_string | abc bcd def xyz |
| p_match_type | OR |
| l_sql_statement | SELECT email_address FROM customers WHERE 1 = 0 OR email_address LIKE '%abc%' OR email_address LIKE '%bcd%' OR email_address LIKE '%def%' OR email_address LIKE '%xyz%' |